# How to mock "fluent" DataSourceHealthIndicator?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-test

I am using `Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE`.

I have this piece of code in my **controller**, where i am using the "free" `DataSourceHealthIndicator` to check if the DB is DOWN:

```
@Autowired 
private DataSourceHealthIndicator d;

//some code

if("DOWN".equals(d.getHealth(false).getStatus().getCode())) {
 // do something
} else {
 // proceed
}
```

Now, in my slice test, i would like to mock it(the `DataSourceHealthIndicator`), but i have a null pointer, as obviously getHealth() is not returning a Health object, getStatus() is not returning a Status object...

```
@WebMvcTest
//some code
@MockBean
private DataSourceHealthIndicator d;
//some code

given(this.d.getHealth(anyBoolean()).getStatus().getCode()).willReturn("UP");
```

How can i go about mocking it?

I tried this:

```
given(this.d.getHealth(anyBoolean())).willReturn(Health.up().build());
given(this.d.getHealth(anyBoolean()).getStatus()).willReturn(Status.UP);
given(this.d.getHealth(anyBoolean()).getStatus().getCode()).willReturn("UP");
```

But it is failing on the 2nd given statement:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
>  Status
>   cannot be returned by getHealth()
>  getHealth() should return Health

Comment: `Mockito.when(d.getHealth(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(something);`

Comment: Hi @AlanHay, I tried it, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry but no one is going to be able to help with an error description of *but couldn't get it to work*

Comment: Hi @AlanHay, look at the edit. Also, this has to do with `mockito deep stubs`, your solution unfortunately does not work.

Comment: It obviiously works perfectly well if you have used it properly.

Comment: Hey @AlanHay, you have a problem with me, is it? Chill down mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *shifted* the *DataSourceHealthIndicator code* to a class of its own.

This has allowed me to easily slice test the Controller layer and at the same time it has allowed me to easily test the other class, with just the `MockitoExtension.class`.

SRP & KISS principle in action.